# Showing that the two definitions of conditional expectations are equivalent.

Tags: probability, definition, conditional-expectation

How do I show that $\displaystyle\sum_{x\in\text{Im}(X)}xP[X=x\mid A] = \dfrac{E[X\cdot1_A]}{P[A]}$, for $A \subseteq \Omega$ a sub-sigma algebra and $X$ a discrete random variable from $\mathcal{F} \to \mathbb{R}$?

The hint was that we should start by assuming that $X$ takes finite many values, and then extend the result to every $X\ge0$. Also, we can write $X(\omega) = \displaystyle\sum_{x\in\text{Im}(X)}x1_{X=x}(\omega)$.

I attempted to expand both sides to get
$$\displaystyle\sum_{x \in \text{Im}(X)} x\mathbb{P}[X = x \mid A] = \displaystyle\sum_{x \in \text{Im}(X)} x\dfrac{\mathbb{P}[X = x \cap A]}{\mathbb{P}[A]}$$
and
$$\dfrac{E[X\cdot1_A]}{\mathbb{P}[A]} = \displaystyle\sum_{x \in \text{Im}(X)} x\dfrac{\mathbb{P}[X\cdot1_A = x]}{\mathbb{P}[A]},$$
then trying to show that for every $x \in \text{Im}(X)$, $\mathbb{P}[X = x \cap A] = \mathbb{P}[X\cdot1_A = x]$. But this is where I got stuck, since $X\ge0$ and not every $\omega$ s.t. $X\cdot1_A(\omega) = x$ is in $A$ if $x = 0$. Also, I'm not entirely sure why is it that we should start by assuming $X$ takes only finite values.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If $A \subseteq \Omega$ then I think you want $A$ to be an event (an element of $\mathcal{F}$) with $P[A]>0$. So, $A$ is not a subsigma algebra.  Since you are dealing with $1_A$, the indicator function of event $A$, this reinforces that $A$ is really an event. Also, a random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ maps $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathcal{F}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  Then, I think the Speltzu answer below gives the derivation you want.

Comment: This assumes the standard probability space notation $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ where $\Omega$ is  the sample space, $\mathcal{F}$ a sigma algebra on $\Omega$, and $P:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow [0,1]$ a probability measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{gather*} 
E[X\cdot 1_A]=E\left[\sum x1_{X=x}\cdot 1_A\right]=\sum xE[1_{X=x}\cdot 1_A]=\sum xE\bigl[E[1_{X=x}|A]\cdot1_A\bigr]=\\
=\sum xE[1_{X=x}|A]E[1_A]=\sum xP[X=x|A]P(A)
\end{gather*}
Another way:
\begin{gather*}
\sum xP[X=x|A].P(A)=\sum xP(X=x\cap A)=\sum xE[1_{X=x}\cdot 1_A]=E\left[\sum x1_{X=x}\cdot 1_A\right]=E[X\cdot 1_A]
\end{gather*}
In general:
$$E[X|A]=\int xdP_{X/A}=\frac{E[X\cdot 1_A]}{P(A)}$$

Comment: Definition of conditional expectation.